# Mageifah and koritz vs aistrah

Tags: tefilla, tznius-modesty

I once heard a story regarding a Mageifah (plague) that happened in the times of Reb Pinchas of Koritz and Reb Yaiva of Austra. Reb Pinchas held it was peritzas that caused it and he had a posuk but Reb Yaiva felt it was talking is Shul and he also had a Possuk.

I don’t remember the details. Can anyone fill me in?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!